# Linq with group by and count by a sub class

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

please help i have no idea.
I have a main entity with a ICollection of sub entities. I want to get a result, grouped by a field in this main entity with a of counts sub entities.
To do it with sql is super easy

```
SELECT 
            me.Status,
            COUNT(se.MainEntityId)
        FROM 
            MainEntity AS me
        LEFT JOIN 
            SubEntity AS se ON me.Id = se.MainEntityId
        -- WHERE conditions can be included here
        GROUP BY 
            me.Status
```

But in linq it's hard to write with server side evaluation

I even tried online tools like chatGpt and linq me up to translate it, but no luck.
For example i get smth like that

```
var query = db.MainEntities
    .GroupJoin(db.SubEntities, me => me.Id, se => se.MainEntityId, (me, se) => new { me, se })
    .SelectMany(x => x.se.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, se) => new { x.me, se })
    .Where(x => x.me.Status != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.me.Status)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Status = g.Key,
        SubCount= g.Count(x => x.se != null),
    });

// Execute the LINQ query
var result = query.ToList();
```

And I get an error that it couldn't be translated

Navigation property:

```
public class MainEntity
{
    public ReportStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; set; }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    public virtual MainEntity MainEntity { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            mb.Entity<SubEntity>()
                .HasOne(a => a.MainEntity)
                .WithMany(u => u.SubEntity)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.MainEntityId);
}
```

Comment: Show us your `DbContext`. Do you have Navigation Properties set-up?

Comment: Updated question, if anything else needed please tell

Comment: `var results = await db.SubEntities.GroupBy( se => se.MainEntity ).Select( grp => new { grp.Key /*MainEntity*/ .Status, Count = grp.Count() } ).ToListAsync();`

Comment: You have this navigation property `SubEntities`. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need left outer join but included any way. You are excluding from count where status is null

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context db = new Context();
            var query = (from me in db.MainEntity.Where(x => x.Status != null)
                         join se in db.SubEntity on me.MainEntityId equals se.Id into ps
                         from se in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { me = me, se = se }
                        ).GroupBy(x => x.me.Status)
                        .Select(g => new { key = g.Key, count = g.Where(x => x.se != null).Count() })
                        .ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<MainEntity> MainEntity { get; set; }
        public List<SubEntity> SubEntity { get; set; }
    }
    public class MainEntity
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int MainEntityId { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use power of navigation properties and avoid joins. You query should looks like this one:

```cs
var query = 
    from me in db.MainEntities
    where me.Status != null
    from se in me.SubEntities.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group se by me.Status into g
    select new 
    {
        Status = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(x => x != null)
    };
```